# Issues in 64bit solaris compiler

Tags: c++, function, 64-bit, parameter-passing, solaris

I use 64bit solaris compiler v5.11 to compile cpp code. I need to call a function (accepts a param as reference) which is defined a lib. While calling function present in a lib, I see that function param values are getting changed. For example, I set a structure (type struct rusage)with all members as 0 and invoke the function . But, once the control reaches the function, I see that some structure member values are not zero. I suspect anything to with sign bit. Strangely, the issue does not exist if I use -g option. Also, the code works fine in 32bit mode and also in linux/ibm. Any help appreciated.

```
  struct rusage start, end; //start is all set to 0

  call: add(start, end);
  function definition:
  add(const struct rusage& addend1, const struct rusage& addend2))
  {
     //rusage start member values changes as per debug statement
  }
```

Comment: Your code and the libs code probably have different structure packing.  You need to set the structure packing the same in the program and the libs.

Comment: Add the following C++ compiler flags to your 64-bit build:  `+w2 -xport64`.  Fix ***all*** the warnings.  You might be dealing with code from too-smart-to-know-what-they're-doing developers who just "know that a pointer fits in an `int`" or that "`size_t` is just an `unsigned int`". Then read `man libumem` and `man umem_debug`, set the envvals you want to control umem memory debugging, run `export LD_PRELOAD_64=/lib/64/libumem.so`, then run your process and see what errors you get.  You should also read `man bcheck`.  The Studio compiler suite comes with extensive memory debugging features.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That too.  But I suspect that would be just a start.  And if this is on SPARC, the poor developers with an x86-only background are going to have a huge wake-up call when they find out they can no longer just stuff any type of variable at any address...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah. It is on SPARC. Looks like structure packing issue. I put cout statements to print the address of the structure 'start' before and inside the function. It is not matching. How do I set the structure packing the same in the program and the libs? struct rusage is part of sys/resource.h

Comment: @AndrewHenle. I added the option you said. I can see following warnings: Converting a 64-bit type value to "int" causes truncation and Converting an "int" into a 64-bit integer causes sign extension